# Mais de um valor para o mesmo appendChild()

Tags: javascript

Como posso concatenar dois valores no mesmo appendChild?

Por ex, transformar isso

```
li.appendChild(_nomeAutorTexto);
li.appendChild(_sobrenomeAutorTexto);
```

nisso

```
li.appendChild(_nomeAutorTexto + espaço + _sobrenomeAutorTexto);
```

---

Aqui o código todo:

```
const listaTextos = document.querySelector("#lista-textos");

function renderLista (doc) {

    let li = document.createElement("li");
    let _nomeAutorTexto = document.createElement("span");
    let _sobrenomeAutorTexto = document.createElement("span");
    let _nomeTexto = document.createElement("span");
    let _livroTexto = document.createElement("span");

    li.setAttribute("data-id", doc.id);
    _nomeAutorTexto.textContent = doc.data().nomeAutorTexto;
    _sobrenomeAutorTexto.textContent = doc.data().sobrenomeAutorTexto;
    _nomeTexto.textContent = doc.data().nomeTexto;
    _livroTexto.textContent = doc.data().livroTexto;

    li.appendChild(_nomeAutorTexto);
    li.appendChild(_sobrenomeAutorTexto);
    li.appendChild(_nomeTexto);
    li.appendChild(_livroTexto);

    listaTextos.appendChild(li);

}
```

---

Essa é uma simples questão de sintaxe ou tenho de fazer algum truque mais sofisticado?

Comment: Se tem todo o código?

Comment: Oi Virgilio: acabei de colocar :-)

Comment: Por exemplo: se você for colocar somente um texto no Li acho que não precisa criar dois `spam` ou esses dados serão formatados com `css` ou só são textos mesmo? ou existe algo de pegar essas informações para desenvolver algo.?

Comment: A final, qual o seu objetivo? Pelo que entendi, seu código está funcionando. Você quer apenas resumir essas linhas do `appendChild()`?

Comment: Veja a sua duvida parece não ter, porque não estou vendo problemas nesse código, só não pode concatenar elementos.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, o codigo funciona, eu só gostaria que as infos _nomeAutorTexto e _sobrenomeAutorTexto ficassem na mesma linha ...

Comment: Crie os valores em um elemento! porque? o `appendChild` só aceita um elemento por vez ele funciona assim, ele foi feito assim. o máximo unir as duas informações em apenas um elemento.

Comment: Exato, @LipESprY: gostaria que as infos _nomeAutorTexto e _sobrenomeAutorTexto ficassem no mesmo appendChild() ...

Comment: Nesse caso, minha resposta volta a ser válida. Não pode. Lógico que dá pra obter o mesmo resultado da sua função de inúmeras formas, mas não tem relação com a sua pergunta. Como o @VirgilioNovic mencionou: você pode colocar tudo em um único elemento. Só que vai mudar o resultado final. Sua `li` vai ter um único `span` com todos os textos "concatenados".

Comment: Opa, ficando claro!

Eu poderia concatenar as informações nessa parte do codigo, para que o conteudo de _nomeAutorTexto incluisse tb _sobrenomeAutorTexto?

_nomeSobrenomeAutorTexto.textContent = (doc.data().nomeAutorTexto + oc.data().sobrenomeAutorTexto)

?

Comment: Foi exatamente isso que o @VirgilioNovic sugeriu: "*- Crie os valores em um elemento!*" Atente-se apenas ao fato de alterar o resultado final. Como ele mesmo já mencionou: "*- se você for colocar somente um texto no Li acho que não precisa criar dois spam ou esses dados serão formatados com css ou só são textos mesmo? ou existe algo de pegar essas informações para desenvolver algo.?*"

Comment: Obrigado, pessoas, vou estudar mais um pouco para implentar a sugestão do @VirgilioNovic.

Grato!

Comment: Se foi resolvido, a solução deve estar na forma de resposta, não como edição da pergunta;

Comment: Grato pelo toque, @AndersonCarlosWoss.

Answer (score 1):

Bom, acho que já foi explicado que nativamente o `appendChild` aceita apenas um argumento, e concatenar objetos também não funciona, pois qualquer concatenação de objetos resulta numa string, o que não serve de parâmetro para `appendChild`.

Porém, há a opção de criar uma função, ou um método que faça o desejado. Você pode até mesmo estender a classe node. Por exemplo, se adicionarmos o método `appendChildren`:

```
Object.defineProperty(Node.prototype, 'appendChildren', {
    configurable: true,
    value: function(...children) {
        for (const child of children) {
            this.appendChild(child);
        }

        return this;
    }
});
```

Poderemos fazer o desejado agora utilizando esse método:

```
li.appendChildren(_nomeAutorTexto, _sobrenomeAutorTexto, _nomeTexto, _livroTexto);
```

Answer (score 0):

> "*- Como posso concatenar dois valores no mesmo appendChild?*"

Não pode. Não é a utilização correta do método.

Conforme a documentação, esta é a sintaxe do método:

```
node.appendChild(node)
```

Onde `node` são os "nós" dos objetos.

Esse método espera um único objeto a ser renderizado/movido para após o último filho do objeto em questão.

Seguindo seu exemplo, `_nomeAutorTexto` e `_sobrenomeAutorTexto` são nós de objetos. Logo, não pode concatenar diretamente na chamada do método esperando que ele renderize/mova ambos objetos.

> Leitura recomendada: [HTML DOM appendChild() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Segue um jeito de implementar se é que entendi direito a pergunta:

```js
var li = document.createElement('LI');           // cria uma tag li
var span1 = document.createElement('span');      // cria a primeira tag span
span1.textContent = 'TEXTO 02';                  // seta um texto na span 01
var span2 = document.createElement('span');      // cria a segunda tag span
span2.textContent = ' TEXTO 03';                 // seta um texto na span 02
var lista = document.getElementById('lista');    // referencia a ul

li.appendChild(span1);                           // adiciona a span 01 no final da ul
li.appendChild(span2);                           // adiciona a span 02 no final da span 01

lista.appendChild(li);                           // adiciona os textos na ul
```

```html
<ul id="lista">
  <li>TEXTO 01</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

A solução que me atendeu foi a seguinte:

1) Criei um spam para nome e sobrenome:

```
let _nomeCompletoAutorTexto = document.createElement("span")
```

2) O conteudo desse spam é a concatenação de dois campos do BD:

```
_nomeCompletoAutorTexto.textContent = doc.data().nomeAutorTexto + ' ' + doc.data().sobrenomeAutorTexto;
```

3) Criei novo appendChild() para essas infos:

```
li.appendChild(_nomeCompletoAutorTexto);
```

4) Final feliz.

Obrigado a todos!